# Android layout that crops rather than resize its children

Tags: android, layout, sliding

I am looking for an android layout (if there exists) that can do the following.

2 images that occupies the entire width of the screen, stacked on top of each other. A slider say 2 or three pixels wide that allows a user to slide across the width of the screen revealing or hiding portions of the images.

Note that the layout like slidingPane does not work in this scenario as it resizes the contents in each pane rather than cropping them which is what I want.

To better describe the question here are some images.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a layout, but achieves what I was after.
Added images to textureviews(1,2), added one of the textureviews(2) to a linearlayout. Added the texureView1 and linearlayout to a framelayout such that the linearlayout is on top. To achieve the above said effect the linearlayout and the textureView(2) that it holds is moved in opposite directions.